# Returning an item from an array in a C function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

So, I'm working on this hangman game. I am having a little trouble with arrays and pointers. This is what I have:

```
char* getword(int index);
int main (void) {

char *secword =  getword(1);
printf("%s ", *secword);
}

char *getword(int index)
{
 char *words[8]= {'bye', 'hi','what', 'cat', 'dog',
                    'bird', 'air', 'water', 'fire'};
return words[index];
}
```

I keep getting a segmentation fault (core dumped) error.

Comment: Strings in C use double quotes. There are also 9 strings in that array, not 8.

Comment: Yeah - how did you manage to get as far as a segfault??

Comment: use `char const *` instead of `char *`, and you either need to use `printf("%s", secword);` or `printf("%c", *secword);`. And pay attention to compiler messages; if there are any warnings or errors don't even bother running your program yet -- fix the mistakes first.

Comment: ..assuming the attempt to return a pointer to a local array does not blow up first, (assuming anything compiles at all).

Comment: if you are returning a value from a variable local to a function use `static`  qualifier so in this case it should be `static char *words[8];`, because when a function returns its stack frame is destroyed and also all its local variables,but if you use `static` you put the variable in the `.data` segment istead of stack

Comment: So I did the suggestions but I still have the core dumped error. I will be back to mingle with this later.

Comment: May I ask why you ignored the warnings (especially after the segfault)? Even if I don't request any warnings, I get 17 for this code with Gcc, and 9 of them are required. This really puzzles me, most of the beginner questions here could be solved simply by reading warnings. Is there a popular IDE which doesn't show them by default or something?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using code blocks and the warnings exist, but they don't stop the program from running. If my program compiles and runs, I kind of forget about the warnings.

Comment: @Mjalil93: I see, thanks. Gcc and Clang both have the `-Werror` option to turn all warnings into errors, maybe this helps you. In general, with such basic question, it often helps to search for the literal warning message. And maybe have a look at the warning options of your compiler ([Gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options), [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#options-to-control-error-and-warning-messages)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have four important mistakes

1. You can't use `words` outside of the `getword()` function be cause it's allocated in the stack frame of the function.

   So when the function returns, the array is deallocated and thus undefined behavior happens.
2. Your array doesn't contains strings but instead **multicharacter contants**.
   Multicharacter constants are valid, but are implementation defined so you can't rely on them for a portable program.

   Your code compiles because you didn't enable warnings, and then the integer value which is dependent on the implementation of multicharacter constants is assigned to the poitners of the array, when you try to access the addresses at these values for printing them then undefined behavior happens.
3. `printf()` expects a `char` pointer for each `"%s"` specifier, `*secword` has type `char` so that's also wrong, it's compiling again because you didn't enable compiler warnings.
4. You are initializing the array with `9` words, instead of `8`, another problem that would be reported by compiler warnings.

You have 2 options

1. Make `words` static in the `getword()` function

   ```
   const char *getword(int index);
   int main (void) 
   {
       char *secword =  getword(1);
       printf("%s\n", secword);
   }

   const char *getword(int index)
   {
        static const char *words[9] = {"bye",   "hi",  "what",  "cat", "dog",
                                       "bird", "air", "water", "fire"
        };
        return words[index];
   }
   ```
2. Declare `words` in main, and pass it to `getword()`

   ```
   const char *getword(int index, const char *words[]);
   int main (void) 
   {
        const char *words[9] = {"bye",   "hi",  "what",  "cat", "dog",
                                "bird", "air", "water", "fire"
        };
        char *secword = getword(1, words);
        printf("%s\n", secword);
   }

   const char *getword(int index, const char *words[])
   {
        return words[index];
   }
   ```

I have been writing c programs for a while now, and I use as many warnings as my compiler can give, if I was a new programmer learning c I would enable even more warnings if possible.

Comment: Have an upvote - I wondered when someone would eventually suggest const.

Comment: The `static` is unnecessary -- while `words` is invalid after return, `words[index]` is (string literals have static storage duration). And in my experience, paying attention to warnings is the more important part than suggesting to request more -- except for 3., the compiler already did warn (if it's not a pre-ANSI compiler, what I assume).

Answer (score 0):

```
char* getword(int index);

int main (void) {  
      char *secword =  getword(1);
      printf("%s ", secword);
}

char *getword(int index)
{
     static char *words[9]= {"bye", "hi","what", "cat", "dog",
                    "bird", "air", "water", "fire"};
    return words[index];
}
```

Should be something like this...

Answer (score 0):

Several things are wrong with your program:

1. When using `char*` variables (or any pointers), you must **always** allocate them memory first with malloc. Don't forget to free it too. An alternative to allocating memory manually is using fix-sized arrays.
2. Don't dereference strings when printing them (`printf( "%s ", *secword )`).
3. Make sure you specify the correct number of elements when declaring an array (there's 9, not 8), and don't forget to check for stepping over array bounds.
4. In C, all strings are double quoted; single quotes denote character constants.